# JavacriptのSetIntervalの処理について

Tags: javascript, html

下記のようなコードでTableauと呼ばれるオブジェクトをSetIntervalでリロードしています。
ただしSetIntervalは定期的にリロード処理の完了、未完了に無関係に実行キューを吐いてしまいます。リロード処理が間に合わない場合更新がとまってしまいので、何かいい方法はないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Tableau JavaScript API</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://servername/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="tableauViz"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");

  var url = "http://servername/t/311/views/Mayorscreenv5/MayorScreenv2";

  var options = {
    hideTabs: true,
    width: "100%",
    height: "1000px"
  };

  var viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);

setInterval(function () {viz.refreshDataAsync() }, 3000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**リロード処理の完了を待って一定時間後に再度リロード処理を行う** という趣旨のコードを記載します。

```
...

// ここを書き換え
// setInterval(function () {viz.refreshDataAsync() }, 3000);
(function loop() {
    viz.refreshDataAsync()
        .then(() => setTimeout(loop, 3000))     // 処理完了から3秒後に再帰実行
        .catch(error => console.log(error));    // TODO: エラー時の処理
})();

...
```

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/setInterval#Ensure_that_execution_duration_is_shorter_than_interval_frequency) ではコールバックの実行時間がインターバル時間よりも長くなるケースにおいて、再帰的な `setTimeout()` のパターンを推奨しています。

> ロジックの実行時間がインターバル時間より長くなる可能性がある場合は、WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout を使用して名前付き関数を再帰的に呼び出すことを推奨します。

また、[Tableauのドキュメント](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_asynchronous_calls.htm) によると、名前に `Async` と付くメソッドは `Promise` を返すらしいので、
`then()` メソッドのコールバックにて再帰呼び出しを行うことで、リロード処理の完了を待つことができます。  
ただし、この場合のリロード処理の実行間隔は、毎回のリロード処理の所要時間によってまちまちになります。